# Icon over image + y axis positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, font-awesome

I am trying to get my 5 Font Awesome Icons over my background image with a fixed position. That fixed position should allow me to scroll past it whitout any problem. I know that there is a way but i am not finding it.

My HTML:

```
    <!--Kaffe abschnitt -->
    <!--5 Icons-->
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-5x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-rebel fa-5x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-empire fa-5x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitch fa-5x"></i> </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-steam fa-5x"></i> </a></li>
</ul>
    <!--Ende 5 Icons-->
    <!--Hintergrund-->
    <img src="img/bild2.png" class="container-full">
    <!--Ende Kaffe abschnitt -->
```

Background CSS:

```
.container-full {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -999;
}
```

Icon CSS:

```
 ul li {
        list-style-type: none;
        float: left;
    } 
ul li a span {
    background: transparent;
    color: #205D7A;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid;

    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 998;
}
ul li a span:hover {
    opacity: .8;
}
```

I am not asking for a premade full code. Just the name of the actions or some short code snipeds.

Comment: try using a `<span class="fa fa-twitch fa-5x">` .. ?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh a span over all of them or ever icons gets a span for itself?

Comment: every icon gets a span for itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to get my 5 Font Awesome Icons over my background image with a fixed position.

You don't want to use 'position:fixed' if you want to scroll past them.
Instead, use position:absolute.

absolute will position elements according to the first parent that has anything but "position:static", i suggest setting "position:relative" on the parent you want your elements to position them self according to.

If you want your "icons" to be along the right hand side of a div, then it would have looked like this

```
#myDiv{position:relative;} //the container

.myIcons{position:absolute; right:0} //a handy class on all your icons spans/i

.icon1{top:0px} //these are just unique classes per icon
.icon2{top:20px}
.icon3{top:40px}
```

Hope this gets you in the righth direction